How to get a random number only once per instance, in stead of for each vertex, in geometry nodes
I've built this rather complex way to create a box with tape on it in geometry nodes. This is because I need to create many different boxes according to specific size profiles.
The setup works but I have to put in a different seed manually for each box which is plugged into the ID input of the Random node. Otherwise a new random value will be picked for each vertex resulting in a crumpled box.
I want to get rid of the Seed input so a new random box will be created each time. I've tried putting this in a node group and adding a random node to the Seed input but that didn't work either. So how do I get only one random value per box? I'm sure this is easy, and probably a duplicate when you know the answer, but I'm stuck.
This turned out to be a duplicate as I expected. For a different but also elegant solution see this thread:
questions/319805/how-do-you-randomly-translate-vertex-groups-for-individual-instances-for-instanc
This is the part with the random values:

This is the entire node tree but is illegible so the entire belend file is linked at the bottom.

The "crumpled box"

Link to the Blend file:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/8hgvdpb7xbhn97pczy0kn/Pakket01.blend?rlkey=b57ww3luox1p7mj4ikzhoywpw&st=2u777ist&dl=0
Using Blender 4.1

just use store named attribute on domain "instance" after your instance on points node and plugin any random value you need.

Hi Chris, I'm not sure how to connect that up. Should I instance (on ponts) the entire object, or  crate a node group out of this first? and Where does the named attribute go, and what "Name" should I use?

if u provide your blend file, i can update it.

Thanks Chris, There is a dropbox link in the bottom of the question, please let me know if this doesn't work.

Judging by the title alone, here's an example of how to do it: How Do You Randomly Translate Vertex Groups for Individual Instances for Instances on Points?

Thanks Markus, that is also a very elegant solution. Especially the island index is very nice. It avoids the Capture attribute that always baffles me. I never know what to use as input. This makes it a duplicate as I already expected.

i hope, that this is what you want?

So i just made a nodegroup out of your package GN setup and used it in a repeat zone, to position each individual package on a grid.
There was no instance on points node in your setup - so i was not sure what you wanted...hope it helps.
